# Есть ли способ выйти из функции

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть такой метод

```
findEntity(className: any) {
            let result: any;
            this.entities.forEach((e: any) => {
                if (e instanceof className) {
                    result = e;
                    return;
                }
            });
            return result;
        }
```

Можно ли как то одним ретурном выйти и из цикла и из метода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой вариант не подойдет?

```
findEntity(className: any) {
    return this.entities.find((e: any) => (e instanceof className));
}
```

или такой

```
findEntity(className: any) {
    for(let e: any in this.entities){
        if(e instanceof className) return e;
    }
}
```

forEach это всё же метод, а не цикл

Comment: подойдет спасибо